# Separate path for .zcompdump files

Tags: zsh

I understand `.zcompdump-*` files are dumped configuration files that can speed up completion and that can be deleted safely. I would like to store them in a separate location since they clutter my home directory. What's a good way of doing so?

I know one option is to use the `ZDOTDIR` variable but that would force me to place **all** my zsh dot files in that location. I just want to store the `.zcompdump` files elsewhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `.zshrc`, change the invocation of `compinit` to add a `-d` option with the location of the file. For example:

```
compinit -d ~/.cache/zsh/zcompdump-$ZSH_VERSION
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I assume I can still invoke this after loading oh-my-zsh ?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina No, you have to change the place where `compinit` is invoked. If you invoke it twice, it'll create the file each time, with the name supplied on that invocation or as `~/.zcompdump` if you don't pass `-d`. If you want your configuration rather than Robby Russell's, don't use oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Note that the file won't be created if you don't have the `~/.cache/zsh/` directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73330903/13992057